# Complex modulus? No, not the absolute value.

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was trying to make a class for complex numbers (VB.NET) but then I stumbled upon a problem. How do I define the $mod$ operator for Complex numbers?

First I asked [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%2bbi%29%20mod%20%28c%2bdi%29). It didn't help much. (But at least it told me it was possible to define).

Then, I searched Google, which didn't help much either. The most I found was [this](http://www.freemathhelp.com/forum/threads/76383-Modulo-of-complex-numbers). Didn't help to clarify.

So I want to ask if any of you know how I could extend the $mod$ operator to the Complex numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

(P.S. I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274694/modulo-complex-number?rq=1) question but I didn't see how the accepted answer answered it. What I want is a general formula for complex numbers.)

Comment: Can it be defined?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I told Wolfram to calculate some modulus with complex numbers and it managed to return values. Here's an example:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%2Bi%29+mod+%283-5i%29

Comment: Since $\mathbb{C}$ is not ordered (and since every element of $\mathbb{C}$ is either $0$ or a unit), I don't really know what this would look like.

Comment: @T.Bongers Maybe like this? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%2Bbi%29+mod+3

Comment: If your're talking about Gaussian *integers* $\,m+ni,\,\ m,n\in\Bbb Z\,$ then they  have a Euclidean division algorithm using the norm $\,m^2+n^2\,$ as a measure of size. If not, you need to say more for the question to make sense.

Comment: @BillDubuque It's $\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$. But yes, I'm talking 'bout that.

Comment: @AnonymousPi For the Gaussian integers $\,\Bbb Z[i]\,$ the norm is $\alpha\alpha=m^2+n^2.\,$ Number rings that are Euclidean wrt to the norm are called *norm-Euclidean.* You can find an exposition for Gaussian integers in many number theory textbooks, e.g. Ireland and Rosen; Hardy and Wright; H. Cohn, Advanced Number Theory, etc.

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: @AnonymousPi If your question is how the algorithm of division with remainder generalizes to the Gaussian integers $\,m+ni,\,\ m,n\in\Bbb Z,\,$ then it is answered in said textbooks. If that is not your question then please elaborate.

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry, but all I know from Complex numbers comes not from textbooks, but from Google. And do you **know** the answer?

Comment: @AnonymousPi It's not hard to find the pertinent pages of those books in Google Books (or even to find online copies of those books). This is best visualized using diagrams that I don't have time to use software to draw (but is in many books).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using some modulus formulas but they didn't give the same results as W|A. Then I tried using the "alternate representations". They **didn't** give the same results! I figured out it was a bug and managed to make this general formula: $$(a+bi)\bmod (c+di)=a+bi+(c+di)\lceil-\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\rceil$$ Hope this helps someone else!

P.S. $\lceil a+bi\rceil = \lceil a\rceil + \lceil b\rceil i$

Comment: How do you define the ceiling of a complex number?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Edited ;)

Comment: That doesn't look like it jibes with the results of the euclidean division algorithm.  For instance, it seems very likely that there are cases where your definition would give $|(a+bi)\bmod (c+di)| \gt |c+di|$, which is the essential property for modulus.